# mysql opposite of inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to contact my users via email using my database. I want to make sure that I don't accidentally contact the same user twice. For that, I have a table that tracks who got contacted and when.

When I do my MYSQL query I want to select emails from the the `email` table and make sure none of those entries exists in the `contacted` table.

To phrase it in a sentence: select email from Email_Table if they are not in Contacted_Table

Perhaps there is a completely different approach. I am open to all suggestions :)Thank you :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
select email 
from Email_Table t1 
where not exists (select email 
                  from Contacted_table t2 
                  where t1.email = t2.email)
```

**OR**

```
select email 
from Email_Table t1 
where email not in (select email 
                    from Contacted_table)
```

Comment: what is the best way to add condition to the first statement? like : no entries from a particular date ( where t1.email=t2.email AND t2.date=2011-01-01) for some reason it is not working for me

Comment: Which is the most efficient way; `LEFT JOIN` with where or this, your answer?

Comment: I think it depends, checkout your execution plan and see it in action.

Comment: Subqueries are to be avoided; use one of the solutions that accomplishes it with a left join.

Answer (score 44):

Try this

```
SELECT email FROM email_table e 
LEFT JOIN contacted_table c ON e.email = c.email
WHERE c.email IS NULL
```

Comment: +1. You could have written `USING(email)` too. Makes it even more readable.

Comment: the Contacted_table would have a date column in it so I might have the email in it from a previous mailout . I just wanna make sure that it does not have that email on a particular date.... so essentially i need to add another condition on the "contacted_table". What would be the best way?

Comment: This is a fantastic solution that took me 5 minutes to wrap my head around.

Comment: Excellent solution and much more robust compared to using WHERE NOT EXISTS or WHERE NOT IN, etc. even though those also work.

Comment: @LinusKleen Can you explain how you would use `USING(email)`?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter It's not my answer. I only edited it seven years ago. But yeah, I'd prefer the much shorter `USING(email)` instead of `ON e.email = c.email`.

Comment: @LinusKleen Oh nice. Didn't even know that you could do that. I imagine that only works when the column names are the same on both?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter Yes. [See the reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) for details. Scroll down to the "USING" bullet point.

Answer (score 16):

If you try to do a left join like this:

```
SELECT users.email, contacted.email
FROM users LEFT JOIN contacted ON users.email = contacted.email
```

You will get a similar result:

```
users.email | contacted.email
-----------------------------
aa@aa.com   | aa@aa.com
bb@bb.com   | bb@bb.com
cc@cc.com   | cc@cc.com
dd@dd.com   | NULL
ee@ee.com   | NULL
```

Your goal  is to get those record which do not have a match in the `contacted` table, so your query would be:

```
SELECT users.email
FROM users LEFT JOIN contacted ON users.email = contacted.email
WHERE contacted.email IS NULL
```

Comment: NULL is not equal to NULL, use `WHERE contacted.email IS NULL` instead

Answer (score 0):

DELETE email_table
FROM email_table INNER JOIN contacted
ON email_table.email_id = contacted.email_id;

Comment: This deletes records from the email_table. The question was how to retrieve emails that aren't also in the contacted table. Be careful not to suggest destructive results when it's not the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).