# Complex-ish MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm setting up a new database scheme for an auction website and trying to send email to users for when specific items they're looking for are posted. I have three tables:

```
auctions
```

-each item that is posted by user gets an entry here with the title, a googleID, current bid, etc.

```
alerts
```

-these are setup by users and they include the googleID of the item they're looking for, their user ID, an enabled boolean and a timestamp

```
notifications
```

-this keeps track of which users have been alerted about which items so that we don't alert the same user about the same item every time our cron.php is run. Includes alert ID and the auction ID

So I'm trying to create a query that Selects the following:

- alert is enabled in `alerts` table
- googleID in `alerts` table matches googleID in `auctions` table
- auction is not closed in `auctions` table
- alert ID & auction ID in `notifications` table are not on the same row (this is the part I'm having trouble with. I need to make sure a single auction ID can have multiple alerts sent out for it, but never the same auction to any user multiple times)

This is the query I have so far, but I'm really stuck on that last part and I've looked everywhere I can think of for this. Hopefully I've explained myself enough, let me know if any clarification would help and thanks in advance!

```
$sql = "SELECT a.user, b.id, b.title, b.googleimg, b.authors
        FROM alerts a, auctions b, notifications c
        WHERE a.googleID = b.googleid AND a.enabled = 'y' AND b.closed = 0 AND ????";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about -

```
SELECT
    alerts.user,
    auctions.id,
    auctions.title,
    auctions.googleimg,
    auctions.authors 
FROM alerts   
INNER JOIN auctions
    ON alerts.googleID = auctions.googleID
LEFT JOIN notifications
    ON alerts.alertID = notifications.alertID
    AND auction.auctionID = notifications.auctionID
WHERE alerts.enabled = 'y'
AND auction.closed = 0
AND notifications.alertID IS NULL
```

Comment: This was giving me empty results, but if I changed the last line to NOT NULL, I got exactly the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve. Any Ideas? Thanks again

Comment: Also, to help clarify, what I'm trying to do is similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585225/mysql-opposite-of-inner-join

However, I want to be able to email each user multiple times, as long as it is a different auction id, in other words each user can only be identified once per auction ID

Comment: If you got an empty result it is because you have entries in notifications for all auction alerts. If you are sure this is not the case please post a specific example.

Comment: Ah I realized I had deleted the alert that I was expecting to come up. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Changed the syntax to modern JOIN syntax

```
SELECT a.user, b.id, b.title, b.googleimg, b.authors
FROM alerts a  
JOIN auctions b ON b.googleID = a.googleID
JOIN notifications c ON C.auctionID = b.auctionID AND a.alertID<>c.alertID
WHERE a.enabled = 'y' AND b.closed = 0
```

The first two tables are the same as what you are doing.   The third join finds all notifications related to this auction where the alertID in **alerts** is not already in **notifications**.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused but I still need the to be able to send out multiple email per alert ID, but they cannot be for the same auction ID, won't this only select records that do not have an alertID in notifcations table at all?